# How to find the value of this trigonometric expression

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

I am new to trigonometry. I need to evaluate the below expression:

$$ 96\sqrt{3} \ \sin\left(\frac \pi {48}\right) \cos\left(\frac \pi {48}\right) \cos\left(\frac \pi{24}\right)\cos\left(\frac \pi {12}\right) \cos\left(\frac \pi 6\right) $$

I need to use **basic identities**, such as double angle formulae, Trigonometric ratios

Comment: Do you know abou the half angle formulas?

Comment: we get $$\sin(\pi/48)=\frac{1}{4} \left(-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}-\sqrt{2
   \left(2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}\right)}-\sqrt{\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)
   \left(2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}\right)}\right)+\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{3}
   \left(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}+\sqrt{2
   \left(2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}\right)}-\sqrt{\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)
   \left(2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}\right)}\right)$$

Comment: @ovi Yes, how to use it here

Comment: Borrow a 2 from the 96 and put it with the first $\sin$ and $\cos$.  Use the identity $2\sin x \cos x = \sin 2x$.  Repeat.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner : To say the least, that's definitely the hard way! See my answer below.

Comment: thats alright Mr. Hardy

Comment: "I need to use basic identities, such as double angle formulae, Trigonometric ratios."  [You will find many such identities, including double angle formulae on Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities).  Then you can examine them, and apply the ones you need so you can answer your question.  Google might also be a means to access the many, many, easy to find documents and web sites in which you can find all the information you needed here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
96\sin(\pi/48)\cos(\pi/48) = 48 \times \underbrace{2\sin\left(\frac \pi {48} \right) \cos\left( \frac \pi{48}\right)} = 48 \underbrace{\sin\left( 2\times\frac \pi{48} \right)}
$$
by the usual double-angle formula, and then
$$
= 48\sin \left( \frac \pi {24}\right).
$$
Next, do the same thing with $24$ that we just did with $48,$ then with $12,$ then with $6.$